# Python: In pyqtgraph, how to obtain the axes range of a PlotWidget

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm working with the plot of pyqtgraph. There is a built-in function viewRange() returns the axes range of the view box, rather than the plot itself. Is there any function or variables store the axes range of the plot?

Answer (score 5):

Note that the range will give you the current view limits (e.g. if you are zoomed), you can get both the current view range and full x/y axis limits with:

```
plot.getViewBox().state
```

which is a dict with quite a few useful parameters.

Comment: If you're only interested in the view range, you can get it on its own with `plot.getViewBox().viewRange()` which returns a list like `[[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]`

Answer (score 3):

You can access to axes range from AxisItem.
Here is sample code.

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui #from PyQt4 import QtGui
import pyqtgraph

# make window
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) # construct a QApplication (must).

mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
mw.resize(800,800)
mw.setWindowTitle('my qt window')

# make view
view = pyqtgraph.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
# view.show()
mw.setCentralWidget(view)
mw.show()

# make plot area
w1 = view.addPlot(title = "my plot area")

# plot data
# mkPen(color,width,name)
w1.addLegend(offset=(0, 0))
w1.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[3,6,5,8,7],pen=pyqtgraph.mkPen(1, width=1),name="foo")
w1.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[5,7,6,2,9],pen=pyqtgraph.mkPen(2, width=1),name="bar")

axX = w1.getAxis('bottom')
print('x axis range: {}'.format(axX.range)) # <------- get range of x axis
axY = w1.getAxis('left')
print('x axis range: {}'.format(axY.range)) # <------- get range of y axis

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Maybe its my specific application but if you try setting the axis with the range from the above method (in a dynamic type "update" case), it causes the range to grow in size. Not sure if this is a glitch lower level in pyqtgraph but the expectation is setting the axis range with current axis range found above should not change the axis range on the next update...

Comment: Update: ended up being me not reading closer. There was a default argument `padding`  in the `setYRange` which is set to either 0.02 or 0.1 depending on the size of the viewBox. The fix was to set this to zero in the function call.